# Visualizing an LDA model, using Python

Tags: python, data-visualization, lda, topic-modeling

I have a LDA model with the 10 most common topics in 10K documents. Now it's just an overview of the words with corresponding probability distribution for each topic.

I was wondering if there is something available for python to visualize these topics?

Answer (score 6):

[pyLDAvis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyLDAvis/1.0.0) looks reasonably good.

There's also [Termite](https://github.com/uwdata/termite-visualizations) developed by Jason Chuang of Stanford.

Comment: @user3050590 are you sure? It's a port of the R package with the same name which appears to be written in R itself, so should be platform independent. Do you have R installed? Do you have pyLDAvis installed in R? Without those it won't work..

Comment: the problem was with windows installation for scipy package which was not allowing the pyLDAvis to install..

Comment: @user3050590 I'd recommend using anaconda python, scipy problems ought to be solved there (:

Answer (score 4):

There some visulizations you can choise.

In the topic of [Visualizing topic models](http://tedunderwood.com/2012/11/11/visualizing-topic-models/), the visualization could be implemented with,

- D3 and Django(Python Web), e.g. [Circle Packing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530), or [Site Tag Explorer](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassites/d3nodefocus), etc
- [Network X](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/creating-network-graphs-with-python)

In this topic [Visualizing Topic Models](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/papers/ChaneyBlei2012.pdf), the visualization could be implemented with

- Matplotlib
- Bokeh
- etc.

Answer (score 3):

[PyLDAVis](https://pyldavis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) - Visualization tool for LDA Models

Useful [article](https://markroxor.github.io/gensim/static/notebooks/gensim_news_classification.html) for learning **Topic Modelling** using different models in ***Python***

Comment: Answers that are basically just external links will not age well. Can you provide some relevant details here in order to make the answer stand-alone?

Answer (score 2):

Word clouds are popular ways of visualizing topic distributions. To generate a word cloud in python consider cloning the *wordcloud* library.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12061149)

Comment: removed reference to links

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon the use case, you may chose some of these Visualizations as well.

1)Stacked Bar Chart

2)Heatmap

3)Table (https://de.dariah.eu/tatom/topic_model_visualization.html)

4)Histogram

5)Violin Plot (https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/05/data-visualization-python/)

Most of these visualizations are possible thorough **Matplotlib library** in Python.