# Topic modelling nmf/lda scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, visualization, lda, topic-modeling

I am using the great library scikit-learn applying the lda/nmf on my dataset.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from time import time

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF, LatentDirichletAllocation
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

n_samples = 2000
n_features = 1000
n_topics = 5
n_top_words = 5


def print_top_words(model, feature_names, n_top_words):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        print("Topic #%d:" % topic_idx)
        print(" ".join([feature_names[i]
                        for i in topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]]))
    print()


# Load the 20 newsgroups dataset and vectorize it. We use a few heuristics
# to filter out useless terms early on: the posts are stripped of headers,
# footers and quoted replies, and common English words, words occurring in
# only one document or in at least 95% of the documents are removed.

print("Loading dataset...")
t0 = time()
dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(shuffle=True, random_state=1,
                             remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
data_samples = dataset.data
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))

# Use tf-idf features for NMF.
print("Extracting tf-idf features for NMF...")
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2, #max_features=n_features,
                                   stop_words='english')
t0 = time()
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data_samples)
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))

# Use tf (raw term count) features for LDA.
print("Extracting tf features for LDA...")
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2, max_features=n_features,
                                stop_words='english')
t0 = time()
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data_samples)
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))

# Fit the NMF model
print("Fitting the NMF model with tf-idf features,"
      "n_samples=%d and n_features=%d..."
      % (n_samples, n_features))
t0 = time()
nmf = NMF(n_components=n_topics, random_state=1, alpha=.1, l1_ratio=.5).fit(tfidf)
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))

print("\nTopics in NMF model:")
tfidf_feature_names = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print_top_words(nmf, tfidf_feature_names, n_top_words)

print("Fitting LDA models with tf features, n_samples=%d and n_features=%d..."
      % (n_samples, n_features))
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=n_topics, max_iter=5,
                                learning_method='online', learning_offset=50.,
                                random_state=0)
t0 = time()
lda.fit(tf)
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))

print("\nTopics in LDA model:")
tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)
```

where in dataset=fetch_20newsgroups I give my datasets which is list with topics. The program works well and output topics (nmf/lda) as plain text like here:

```
Topics in NMF model:
Topic #0:
don people just think like
Topic #1:
windows thanks card file dos
Topic #2:
drive scsi ide drives disk
Topic #3:
god jesus bible christ faith
Topic #4:
geb dsl n3jxp chastity cadre
```

How can I visualise there results? I cannot understand the vector/mathematics code behind the implementation. Is there any way to visualise the output with plots ? the bag of words also ?I am interested in the nmf results only. I am really bad at visualising things.

Comment: Have a look at visualizing topic model results [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397550/visualizing-an-lda-model-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Termite: http://vis.stanford.edu/papers/termite
Source code is here: https://github.com/StanfordHCI/termite

Answer (score 0):

you could use https://pypi.org/project/pyLDAvis/ these days, very attractive inline visualization also in jupyter notebook